# Selenium Class instantiation

Tags: c#, selenium

Hello I am have trouble using a method from an Instantiated class. I am rather new to selenium and C#, but here is my code to start...

**class 1**

```
 [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        Class2 myClass2 = new Class2();

        static IWebDriver webDriver;

        [AssemblyInitialize]
        public static void invokeBrowser(TestContext context)
        {
            webDriver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\Selenium\");
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            myClass2.RandomMethod();
        }
```

**class 2**

```
[TestClass]
    public class Class2
    {
        static IWebDriver webDriver;
        public void invokeBrowser(TestContext context)
        {
            webDriver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\Selenium\");
        }


        [TestMethod]
        public void RandomMethod()
        {
            webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://google.com");
        }
    }
```

my error happens in `Class1` during my `testmethod` that I am using to call the `Randommethod` from my other class

```
Message: Test method CheckRequest.UnitTest1.TestMethod1 threw exception: 
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I have been struggling with this error for a while and I just dont understand what I am doing wrong. The only object that I am setting is my `webdriver`. Is the issue that I am creating two different webdriver objects? Thanks for your time, and any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Your Class2 never actually instantiates the webDriver.  Is that intentional?  Just because you built it in Class1 doesn't mean anything to Class2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        Class2 myClass2 = new Class2();

        public static IWebDriver webDriver;

        [AssemblyInitialize]
        public static void invokeBrowser(TestContext context)
        {
            webDriver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\Selenium\");
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            myClass2.RandomMethod();
        }
}

//Class2
[TestClass]
    public class Class2
    {
        //[TestMethod]
        public void RandomMethod()
        {
            UnitTest1.webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://google.com");
        }
    }
```

[AssemblyInitialize] method will be called before any method in the project, so wedDriver will have value.  TestMethod1 will call RandomMethod(), if you keep [TestMethod] for RandomMethod, it will be executed twice, as each [TestMethod] will be ran, when you run all the TestMethods.  Is that what you need.